# Does Binding Property guarantee it's invoked on Main Thread? (Xamarin.forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I launched app with using Xamarin.forms.

I'm curious that if this pattern guarantee it's invoked on Main Thread.

In below code, 
UpdateBaby(); will be running on Main Thread?

If not, should I call it with using Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread if it's handling UI?

I asked this because there is possibility that property is changed on background thread. (like from bluetooth or network thread)

Thanks.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty SensorActivityStateProperty = BindableProperty.Create("SensorActivityState", typeof(eSensorActivityState), typeof(BabyShowAbsoluteLayout), eSensorActivityState.NoWearing, BindingMode.Default, null, SensorActivityStateChangedDelegate);
        public eSensorActivityState SensorActivityState { get { return (eSensorActivityState)GetValue(SensorActivityStateProperty); } set { SetValue(SensorActivityStateProperty, value); } }
        static void SensorActivityStateChangedDelegate(BindableObject bindable, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
        {
            BabyShowAbsoluteLayout babyLayout = bindable as BabyShowAbsoluteLayout;
            babyLayout.UpdateBaby();
        }
```

Comment: are you using ViewModels?

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze I don't use MvvMCross but, I think I'm using MvvM pattern for many of my codes. But the my question is for some special cases.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

short answer: no

longer answer: still no

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14514213)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it _is_ actually the right answer

Comment: this should be a comment, or you should explain why it's not possible. You did not write Xamarin.forms your self so you have to back your assertions.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre "You did not write Xamarin.forms your self" actually, I did...

Comment: Good for you, but you still have to explain better than that. Actually, I don't care. Wasn't the one who flagged the post in the first place. Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre and StephaneDelcroix Thanks for your comments and answer. If so, the XF's UI built in Xamarin.forms has process inside that is invoking jobs on MainThread (Otherwise it will be a problem if I change its property on background thread), for example Label's Text Property or many of those. and if I wanna write simillar things I have to follow it(Invoking on Main Thread). Is that correct?

Comment: @BrightLee, yes, if you change properties from a different thread, you should wrap that in `Device.BeginInvokeOnMinThread()` call.